# Cooperation between Activities

Tags: android

I have plugged in lock screen logic into my app. It shows ComfirmPatternActivity (above my MainActivity) which controls graphical pin code input to be correct.
When onCreate() method of MainActivity is call everything is OK. But I also want to lock screen when I simply turn app down not destroying MainActivity. So it goes from onRestart() -> onResume(). In onResume() I placed method handleLockScreen(); as in onCreate(). But for now I got into infinite loop hich shows me ComfirmPatternActivity screen for ages. It seamed out that the last command of code in ComfirmPatternActivity after user inputs correct pin - is Activity finish(). After that finish() Im redirected to MainActivity.onResume() - prev Activity on the stack - in which I again start ComfirmPatternActivity() and so on. I want resume logic only in case user pressed on app icon again, not in case top Activity is destroyed. How this can be handled? Thx in advance.

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    handleLockScreen();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handleLockScreen();
```

..

public void handleLockScreen(){

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("LOCK_SCREEN",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lock_screen_code = prefs.getString("LOCK_SCREEN_CODE","");
    if (lock_screen_code.isEmpty()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampleSetPatternActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampleConfirmPatternActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

public class SampleConfirmPatternActivity extends ConfirmPatternActivity {

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("LOCK_SCREEN",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String patternSha1 = prefs.getString("LOCK_SCREEN_CODE","");
    return TextUtils.equals(PatternUtils.patternToSha1String(pattern), patternSha1);
```

... **finish() is called further in this activity**
    }

This finish() returns to my onResume() which triggers all over again. And I want handle onResume() only in case smth external happend to my app like user returned to my app etc. I dont want get back to onResume() when pin code is checked and everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly declare a boolean (global to application) in LockScreen Activity to fix this issue and tell(to the MainActivity) if it is coming to onResume from outside or from LockScreen (y)